# Axios jsonp request not resolving and blocking code

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I wrote a function to get Google suggestions :

```
const getGoogleSuggestions = async (searchInput: string) => {
  const results = await axios({
    url: `https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=${searchInput}`,
    adapter: jsonpAdapter,
    callbackParamName: "jsonCallback"
  });
  console.log("test")
  return results.data[1];
};
```

It once worked but now it seems not to and I don't understand why.
The `console.log` isn't executed at all. It seems the promise decided not to resolve. Also, when I check the "Network" tab on my browser every request is sent and has a 200 response code.

I tried with a try, catch block, I tried to resolve the promise with `then`... It just doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: remove `callbackParamName`

Comment: @Thomas thanks it works, it's due to a recent update?

Comment: no, your `callbackParamName` is simply wrong and not supported/recognized by the google query API.

Comment: @Thomas add it as an answer! That was a good catch!

Answer (score 0):

With this parameter "client=chrome" the url sends you a text file to download.
Try with replace this by "output=toolbar" for getting an xml in your response.